# 2011 Moderator Election - Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The election results [have been posted](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election) and the moderators are...

[image][image][image]

Thanks for voting and I think I can speak for Anders and SPDoctor when I say we look forward to serving as moderators!

Comment: Yup. And go easy on the newbie!

Answer (score 6):

While I think it is a good idea to limit the number of mods, I would like say that there were some great choices up for the vote.  The contributions of each of the members are appreciated and I hope they continue!